# Javascript: Changing innerHTML vs display

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, displaytag

I'm developing a web form, where I want different inputs to appear depending on what the user previously selects. So I was wondering what's the difference between having an empty div and changing what it contains with innerHTML vs. having several div elements, setting the display to none, and changing which to show up depending on the user input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost always far more efficient to hide and show elements as required, rather than creating them and then destroying them.

This is principally because adding nodes to the document is a computationally expensive operation, even though `innerHTML` is highly optimised. Secondarily, it is because destroying elements also means you destroy any event handlers stored on those elements, which means you have to rebind them, which naturally takes time and unnecessary code.

Another advantage is that Javascript won't work if the user has disabled it or is using a browser that doesn't support it, e.g. a screen reader. If all your elements are present in your original HTML, the page will at least make some sense to these users.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should touch innerHTML as little as possible instead working with javascript commands like createElement and appendChild.

A lot of innerHTML manipulation is comsidered somewhat of an anti-pattern in javascript.

That said, if you have a single form or 2-3 forms you go ahead and do what works for you. Meaning what you see as easier to understand and more maintainable code.

At those scales I doubt anyone would notice the performance gain/defecit by using either approach. Personally I'd probably set the display to none.

Comment: `innerHTML` is often much faster than the DOM methods, because browsers are *very* good at parsing HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure that is true any more and in general anything that causes a reflow should be avoided as much as possible. I would however love to see some benchmarks if you know any. Crockford is strongly against changing the innerHTML property vs dom methods but then again he is also against a lot of other faster things

Answer (score 1):

If you have your div ready, simply change the display :

- the code is simpler
- you have only one storage place for your content (the divs)
- the dom doesn't have to be recomputed by the engine

That's the standard solution when dealing for example with tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the elements with `innerHTML`, then when the form is submitted ONLY the inputs that are shown will be submitted.

By hiding elements with `display`, they are still present in the form and will still be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

it will be faster if you are selecting divs by classes and ids and turning them on and off. However i would just use innerHTML if its just simple text because you wont notice the speed difference. Unless there is a reason to have different divs IE the selections have drastically different contents ie maybe a graph vs text vs table then i would make different divs.

in short they both do the same thing though.